# How to report suspicious downvotes?

Tags: support, downvotes

I regularly check the [sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore) tag and when I just checked it seemed as if all questions in the last 24 hours have been downvoted, seemingly for no reason. The questions are valid, do not appear to be offtopic, and the downvoting appears to be systematic across posts by multiple users, on multiple Sitecore-related topics.

Comment: I'm not really sure, but I think since it is not targeting a specific user, just a tag you can't do anything against it, since votes are anonym and a user can upV and downV what he wants. I think the only thing which you can do is to go through and see which questions you find good and give them an upV.

Comment: All questions have a CV which suggest asking on SuperUser.com...which is wrong for most of them, if not all.

Comment: I left a comment on the posts involved

Comment: I though down-voting for the hell of it was just standard on SO...

Comment: Somebody got fed up with `Sitecore` and decided to blow some steam on SO?

Comment: How can you define a downvote as invalid? I'm curious.

Comment: Counter attack by upvoting random stuff in a tag maybe?

Comment: @Sobrique Careful, we don't want to start the Great Voting Wars of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I supposed the word 'invalid' is an absolute term, when I am looking at something subjectively. It appears, by analyzing the posts and the voting/closing activity occurring, combined with the lack of comments added explaining the rationale that this was not a downvote based in fact. Hence the term 'invalid'. I had hoped there was some sort of moderation that could be done, or somebody I could reach out to for investigation.

Comment: Then any unexplained downvote would be "invalid". Sadly, we mostly never know why a downvote as occured. Even commenter that points out things that could be improved might not have downvoted. I understand what you were looking for but found the use of invalid strange.

Comment: I've altered the title to 'suspicious' to explain the scenario better. I'm looking for what steps to take when suspicious activity is occurring. @mason directed to the Help Center for serial downvoting helps

Comment: Users these days have weird reasons to down vote, recently I get some comments on my answer saying that they are too briefed and hence -1 so you cannot justify whether a vote in invalid or not unless its in bulk or at regular intervals...

Comment: I've lost confidence in the system. I provided an answer to a question on StackOverflow Meta, and since it didn't appeal to the status quo there, it received dozens of down votes. More importantly, as pertains to this question, suddenly programming questions I asked on S.O. that have been sitting idle for months are being attacked with down votes in less than 24 hours. This is more than coincidence. It is corruption and abuse by a small number of vindictive members.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36750812/woocommerce-composite-products-trying-to-set-sku-on-variation-gives-variation-s

Comment: what is the reason for downvoting this post?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78018414/how-to-add-adjusted-pvalue-to-the-correlation-analysis

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Disclaimer, I haven't looked at those specific questions.

But there's no such thing as "invalid downvotes", and that's what I want to address in my post. People are free to use downvotes as they see fit. People have various reasons for downvoting a post. Often, it's because it breaks a rule or shows no research effort.

The only exception to this is serial downvoting (or upvoting), where someone is targeting a particular person, often in retaliation for some perceived slight. That situation is covered in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed).

Comment: *"The only exception to this is serial downvoting (or upvoting), where someone is targeting a particular person"* Here, someone appears to be targeting a particular tag. What do you think about that?

Comment: @Radiodef I don't think the tag will be offended. Perhaps someone thought there's some pertinent details left out of those questions. It's hard to know. Do we really want to try to get into the mind behind everyone's downvoting?

Comment: *"I don't think the tag will be offended."* What about the users who posted these apparently reasonable and on-topic questions?

Comment: @Radiodef If it's a single user downvoting questions on a tag, then the effect per user is pretty insignificant.  And if it affects a single user too many times, it will be serial downvoting and get reversed.

Comment: @Radiodef There are many justified reasons for a user to "target a tag".  It could be the user is familiar only with that tag and doesn't feel comfortable voting on posts without that tag.  And who's to stay those posts don't deserve the downvote?  Maybe there is some new information that renders old answers "not best practice" anymore.  Etc.

Comment: Thank you for the help folks... It just seemed like a 'spam' activity that should be flagged in some way, or be able to be reported. I am not personally impacted by this in any way, but seeing multiple users being downvoted just for participating in a community on Stack Overflow seemed rubbed my moral compass the wrong way.

I'll leave it be and let the voting chips fall where they may

Comment: @mason Please don't tell people there's no such thing as invalid downvotes, then tell them there is an exception for serial downvotes. Some people only read for the answer they want to read.

Comment: Let's think about the people who are actually able to read. The other folks will either never get it right or learn someday that words have meaning by themselves.

Comment: @CBauer If someone reads only part of my answer, that's their problem and they are beyond our hope.

Comment: This is not the attitude that a 10k user should take on a meta post with 15+ upvotes and an answer with 30+. This is something that will be referenced by future users and found in search results. I know we want users to always do the right thing, but if you're in IT (I presume you are), you know how infrequently they will do that. I wouldn't give them an opportunity to make that mistake.

Comment: @CBauer 35 people agreed with my wording or felt it wasn't bad enough to detract from the post. There is no such thing as an invalid downvote. There's only serial downvoting. I chose my wording carefully. If someone only reads the first part, they'll leave here thinking there's no such thing as an invalid downvote. Which is just fine, because that's true. I've seen people try to control how others choose to use their votes. That's not right. If someone serial downvotes, well the system fixes that for us so it's not a major concern.

Comment: "There's no such thing as invalid downvotes, except for this case in which there are invalid downvotes." If that's the post you want to keep, by all means. I was just trying to advise you against making a contradiction.

Comment: @CBauer I am certainly fine with it. It's sort of a contradiction, but it conveys strongly the important part that people should walk away with if they only read part of the answer. Like I said, we can easily fix serial downvoting. Fixing people's mindsets, well that's not nearly so easy.

Comment: @mason The point is somewhat moot now that I've changed the title to reference "suspicious" instead of "invalid". The answer here no longer requires to point out invalid versus valid anymore. The important piece is the part about the serial downvoting.

Answer (score 12):

Glancing at the last half dozen or so [sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore) questions in the last day, I think the reason most have been downvoted is that the downvoter probably thinks the question is *not a programming question*. Rather, they suspect that it's a configuration question having to do with setting up a [sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore) site. Unless the question is actually about how to *program* a plugin, etc. for [sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore), it's not a valid question for SO.

Personally, I would probably have downvoted most of those questions as well.

For reference:

- [Sitecore WeBlog Comment moderation enabled, but comments are posted before approval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885517/sitecore-weblog-comment-moderation-enabled-but-comments-are-posted-before-appro)

  I don't understand how this is a programming question.
- [Moving sublayout that contains another sublayout from one placeholder to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885537/moving-sublayout-that-contains-another-sublayout-from-one-placeholder-to-another)

  This question appears to be about an editor tool used with this product, and I am having difficulty understanding how it relates to programming.
- [Sitecore WeBlog Comment moderation enabled, but comments are posted before approval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885517/sitecore-weblog-comment-moderation-enabled-but-comments-are-posted-before-appro)

  Pretty sure this is pure configuration and has nothing to do with programming.
- [Sitecore WeBlog Blog Feeds with Custom Entry templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883688/sitecore-weblog-blog-feeds-with-custom-entry-templates)

  This one is a bit more borderline -- only because it uses the word "XPath" -- but it still seems dubious to me and I'm not sure that the solution will involve any programming.
- [Sitecore ContentSearch by field and relevance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29878202/sitecore-contentsearch-by-field-and-relevance)

  This one might involve programming -- or it might not.  Still seems to me more of a "how do I use Sitecore" question, and not about how to code something.

Comment: Just to comment on this, while Sitecore is a standalone CMS product it is mostly delivered as a platform for CMS implementation. Most questions require programmatic customization to achieve a result (such as search sorting which is a Lucene IQueryable implementation). While some configuration actions can be done to solve some questions, it is almost always necessary to target a Sitecore developer to answer these types of questions.

Answer (score -26):

Leave it alone.

Micromanaging everything will be this network's demise.